# ¿El reCAPTCHA de Google da la opcción de agregar un puzzle?

Tags: recaptcha

Hola comunidad
Es la primera vez que implemento un CAPTCHA en un formulario y pensé que Google me daba la opccion de agregar un puzzle pero no e encontrado nada en su documentación, por lo que me surgió la duda de que si los puzzle que aparecen en algunos sitios web son hechos desde cero por los programadores o usan algunas librería de confianza para implementarlos?
Estoy usando **reCAPTCHA v2**.

Les agradezco cualquier información que me puedan dar.
Esta es la documentación que estoy siguiendo: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display?hl=es-419
 Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google te da lo necesario para validarte como humano, eso incluye un check donde pone "No soy un Robot", Puzzles, un captcha invisible donde solo percibe tu movimiento de mouse y clics o por score como lo hace en la v3. [Puedes ver los diferentes tipos de reCAPTCHA acá](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions?hl=es-419). Y [Leer esto](https://developers.nopecha.com/token/recaptcha2/).

Así mismo en [este post de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395360/how-can-i-check-if-google-recaptcha-v2-puzzle-is-displayed) explican que Google no da una opcion para elegir o ver lo del reCAPTCHA.

En mi caso, uso v3 porque esta mas optimizado y es lo más nuevo y lo que Google recomienda y créeme nunca he visto un Puzzle en mi web. Pero de que funciona, funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha servido de mucho.